# Google maps API V3 method fitBounds()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code that renders a map.

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.4555729, 9.169236),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

panControl: true,
mapTypeControl: false,
panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
},
scaleControl: false,
streetViewControl: false,
streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
            }
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"),
        myOptions);



var Item_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5983128 ,8.9172776);

var myPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4555729, 9.169236);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: Item_1, 
    map: map});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myPlace, 
    map: map});

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(myPlace, Item_1);
map.fitBounds(bounds);

    }
```

Even if the two points are separated from 25 km I get this result:

[image]

While I would like to render a higher level zoom.

Like this

[image]

I use the method **fitBounds()**

```
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(myPlace, Item_1);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This happens because [`LatLngBounds()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) does not take two arbitrary points as parameters, but SW and NE points

use the `.extend()` method on an empty bounds object

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(myPlace);
bounds.extend(Item_1);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/22qte/

Comment: Correct answer. Need to pass SW and NE points to the extend method. However, the fitBounds method should be called once the map is fully loaded, as vanthome answer below:

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
});

You may want to also pass padding=0 to fitBounds like this: 
map.fitBounds(markerBounds, 0);

Answer (score 34):

`LatLngBounds` must be defined with points in (south-west, north-east) order. Your points are not in that order.

The general fix, especially if you don't know the points will definitely be in that order, is to extend an empty bounds:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(myPlace);
bounds.extend(Item_1);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

The API will sort out the bounds.

Comment: Hah! Just beaten to it. iPad keyboards don't make fast typing easy.

Answer (score 33):

I have the same problem that you describe although I'm building up my LatLngBounds as proposed by above. The problem is that things are async and calling `map.fitBounds()` at the wrong time may leave you with a result like in the Q.
The best way I found is to place the call in an idle handler like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a huge help for me because I was geocoding addresses to coords, and then mapping to those coords, but it wasn't working

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem due to the containing HTML not being displayed yet while calling `fitBounds()`, so apparently the zooming couldn't figure itself out. Making sure the map was displayed first before trying to zoom it helped me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save me, this works perfectly, this answer is correct for my case.

Comment: you are a life saver

Answer (score 11):

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

            });
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
bounds.extend(marker.position);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: For me, I had to change from `bounds.extend(marker)` to `bounds.extend(marker.position)`. Thanks