# Ionic Native Google Maps how to show center point and very mark

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Hey guys I'm using Ionic Native Google Maps plugins and I'm trying to show all the points on the screen as well as the user location, I can do that, no problem, the issue is that I need the user's location to be centered in the map AND show all the points around him.

I've been trying to use the put all my points into a `new LatLngBounds` and setting each using the `.extend()` method but it's not working.

Please help

```
async expandRadius() {
    const query = await this.queryPlaces(10);
    get(query).then(nearByPlaces => {
      const foundPlaces = [];
        nearByPlaces.forEach( el => {
          const placesData = {
            distance: Math.floor(this.geo.point(this.centerPoint.latitude, this.centerPoint.longitude)
              .distance(el.geolocation.geopoint.latitude, el.geolocation.geopoint.longitude)),
              ...el
          };
          foundPlaces.push(placesData);
          // THE CENTER ISSUE STARTS HERE //
          const tmp = new LatLng(el.geolocation.geopoint.latitude, el.geolocation.geopoint.longitude);
          this.bounds.extend(tmp);
          this.map.addMarkerSync({
            position: {
              lat: tmp.lat,
              lng: tmp.lng
            },
            icon: {
              url: 'www/assets/icon/pin.png',
              size: {width: 23, height: 33},
            }
          });
        });
        this.map.moveCamera({
          target: this.bounds.getCenter(),
          tilt: 0,
        });
    })
    .catch()
    .finally( async () => await this.loading.dismiss() );
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268033/google-maps-api-v3-method-fitbounds

Comment: Do you want something like that?